# Float not working as expected

Tags: html, css, web, css-float

I have a navigation box, and the "Contact" element isn't fully right justified despite float being set to right.

```
<div id="navwrapper">
    <ul>
        <li class="single">Home</li>
        <li class="double" id="left">About</li>
        <li class="double" id="right">Contact</li>
        <li class="single">Book</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#right {
    float:right;
}
```

Other questions seem to suggest swapping the left and right elements over to get the desired effect, but that didn't work.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TQFzS/)

Comment: Are you talking about a small gap towards the right?

Comment: The gap to the right exists because you have padding on the first elements, and haven't compensated....either put margin-right:2px; on the #right element, or overflow:hidden, on your ul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were missing `overflow:hidden` on your `ul` element.

Check this [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TQFzS/3/).

`overflow:hidden` is recommended on the parent of floating elements. It forces the parent to wrap around all of them, thus preventing weird behaviour as you were experiencing..

Answer (score 1):

I belive you are searching for `margin` but in minus position, for example:

```
#right {
float: right;
margin: 0 -3px 0;
}
```

That will fix your issue

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TQFzS/4/